# Plotting basin boundary

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

How to plot the basin boundary in *Mathematica*?
I have been trying to do this using the system

```
y''[t] == -R y'[t] + (( Y[1] - y[t])/(Sqrt[(X[1] - x[t])^2 + (Y[1] - y[t])^2 + d^2])^3 
                     + (Y[2] - y[t])/(Sqrt[(X[2] - x[t])^2 + (Y[2] - y[t])^2 + d^2])^3 
                     + (Y[3] - y[t])/(Sqrt[(X[3] - x[t])^2 + (Y[3] - y[t])^2 + d^2])^3) 
          - c y[t]

x''[t] == -R x'[t] + ((X[1] - x[t])/(Sqrt[(X[1] - x[t])^2 + (Y[1] - y[t])^2 + d^2])^3 
                     + (X[2] - x[t])/(Sqrt[(X[2] - x[t])^2 + (Y[2] - y[t])^2 + d^2])^3 
                     + (X[3] - x[t])/(Sqrt[(X[3] - x[t])^2 + (Y[3] - y[t])^2 + d^2])^3) 
          - c x[t]
```

It is a magnetic pendulum swinging chaotically about `3` other magnets underneath. `R`,`c`,`d` are all constants,where `r` is air resistance, `d` is the vertical distance of the pendulum from
the floor, `c` is the sping constant of the pendulum. `X[1]`, `X[2]` and `X[3]` (`Y[1]`,`Y[2]` and `Y[3]`) are the coordinates of the magnets.

But I have gotten nowhere.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation of [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html) and [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html).

Comment: @shrx really? where does it discuss basin boundaries in the docs?

Comment: @rcollyer I thought he needed to solve those equations first, because he did not provide any code except the equations themselves.

Comment: @shrx he needs to provide `X`, `Y`, `R`, `c`, and `d` and boundary conditions, but otherwise that is code that would be supplied to the solvers.

Comment: @HQH which basins are you looking for? The basins of attraction for each magnet, or the chaotic basins? They're subtly different. The first is much, much simpler.

Comment: I am sorry. I have not give a clear describe. This issue was come from:[link](http://www.physics.mun.ca/~cdeacon/labs/3900/magnetic_pendulum.pdf)

Comment: @rcollyer  The issue was come from:[link](http://www.physics.mun.ca/~cdeacon/labs/3900/magnetic_pendulum.pdf)